# Why i can't use EarlyStoppingCallback and load_best_model_at_end=False

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to use the trainer over 5 folds. I wanted to add EarlyStoppingCallback to the trainer function to make it stop if the training is not improving. I get this error:
`AssertionError: EarlyStoppingCallback requires load_best_model_at_end = True`
The following is the code I used:

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./logs",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    logging_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    save_total_limit=2,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=False,
    push_to_hub=False,
)

for train_dataset, val_dataset in zip(train_ds, val_ds):
    trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=val_dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
        callbacks=[
            CombinedTensorBoardCallback,
            EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3),
        ],
    )

    train_result = trainer.train()
```

why i can’t use EarlyStoppingCallback and load_best_model_at_end=False? I just want to save the best model at the level of each fold. Another question: is there a way to save the best model among the 5 folds?

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/huggingface-earlystopping-callbacks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Particular to your question please (i) paste the stacktrace error message you are getting from the code you have ran, (ii) why do you need `load_best_model_at_end=False`? (iii) what are you expecting from 5 different folds? Are you expecting 5 best models, one from each fold or 1 best model from 5 different folds?